# how to locate the element in the table in tr td

Tags: java, html, selenium

The HTML code is the following:

```
<div id = ...>
  <table ...>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table ...>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a onclick="…" class="xl" href="#">1111111</a>
```

I need to locate the last cell/element with the value 111111 and click on it.

I tried these Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td/a[contains(text(),'111111')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#']")).click();
```

but it did not work.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: html is on the client side.  Java is on the server side.  Do you want to use javascript?

Comment: No, I should use Java only, this is to create the cucumber automation test and run it. Specifically this element I need to click and continue the test.

Comment: Try this : 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'111111')]"))

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last element that has the value/text of 111111 then I would use findElements and then click the last one:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='111111']"));

int lastElementIndex = listOfElements.size() - 1;

listOfElements[lastElementIndex].click();
```

Comment: You are wanting to click the last element that has the value/text of 111111.  Is this correct?  If so, my answer should do that.

Comment: No, this is a table, a horizontal table where the headers are the first line and the values are the second line. This element is in the first column and the second line, and this element needs to be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get a collection of the text of all the rows in the table body.

```
WebElement container = Webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("/*xpath to <tbody> element here*/")).click();
List<WebElement> tableRows = container.findElement(By.tagName("tr"));
List<String> elementText = new ArrayList<>();
tableRows.foreach(x -> elementText.add(x.getText()));
```

Then search for the last index of that string

```
int indexOfLast = tableRows.lastIndexOf("1111111");
WebElement theLastElement = elementText.get(indexOfLast);
```

Then you could take that last element and use it to find the  tagged element you are looking for,.

```
WebElement myElement = theLastElement.findBy(tagName("a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code :

```
//Storing the value from the table we have to click 
String tablevalue = "111111";

//Get all the WebElements from second line having values
//***We might have to update the xpath***
List<WebElement> allTableValues = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//tr/td//a"));

//Clicking on Element which matches our Value from all Table Values
for(WebElement ele: allTableValues){
    if(ele.getText().equals(tablevalue)){
    ele.click();
    break;
    }
}
```

You can change the value of tableValue variable to use same code to click on other table values as well.

Comment: Thank you. But it looks like this value in the cell dynamically changes with each test :(  Means I need to click always to the first column/second raw cell instead of the value.What is the best way to click on this cell? Thank you.

Comment: If the value of the cell is changing and we want to use the cell value to do it then we can modify the code as : String tablevalue = driver.findElement("FirstCellLocator").getText();